# A fast solution for filtering number using jQuery or pure JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filter, digits

this is my page :
[image]

I use following code to filter records on keyup :

```
function Search() {
        $('.co').show();
        $('.co').each(function () {
            var showco = true;
            for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
                if ($('.txtFilter' + i.toString()).val().trim() != '') {
                    if ($(this).find('.D' + i.toString()).text() != $('.txtFilter' + i.toString()).val()) {
                        showco = false;
                    } ;
                };
            };
            if (!showSim) {
                $(this).hide();
            };
        });
    };
```

It works good for 200 records, but as records may become 5000 or more, it takes too much time and maybe browser hangs.

I know my code is not optimized and I'm sure there are other methods to do that, so what is the best and fastest way to do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try putting your digits into a two-dimensional array, and running your filtering code on that.  Pulling digits out of the DOM in this manner may be too expensive.  The Chrome Dev Tools will tell you how much time you're spending there.

Comment: You want to separate your DOM or View from your data/model.  Search the data, and have the view show the results.

Comment: Looking at the `$('.txtFilter' + i.toString())`, which is done twice in the loop and per row this is done `9` times. As you do `18` selects per `.co` element. That are  `18*5000` for `5000` element. If you would cache that result  before your `.each` this would be always just `9` no matter how many elements you have. Another thing that might be unnecessarily expensive is the `.text()`, but the most expensive part might be `$('.co').show();`, and the `$(this).hide()`. Especially because you first `.show` all and then `.hide()` the one that don't instead of _toggling_ the visibility.

Comment: consider that it is on keyup event, if user uses backspace or delete to remove one digit, the hidden elements should be shown before filter again.

Comment: Another optimization would be to filter over your last results if user is just adding digits, no need to check again the ones you know that won´t match

Comment: What I mean is to `if (!showSim) { $(this).hide(); } else  { $(this).show(); }` but ideally do something like  `if (!showSim && isVisible ) { $(this).hide(); } else if (showSim && !isVisible )   { $(this).show(); }`. Or do I miss your point with the backspace and delete there?